# Accessing server with one command

Tags: server, ssh

How can access a specific Linux server via SSH and enter the password automatically with one command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most secure way to do this would be to set up certificates and not use a password. [How to setup ssh certificates](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server)

Then you can create aliases for each server in you bashrc:

```
alias ssh_server1='ssh user@server1'
```

You could also use a program called sshpass that allows you pass the password as an argument. Then you could set up aliases using that. I'm not really familiar with the program. I would recommend the first option.

Comment: If you are going to use sshpass, use the file method to send the password for a little more security.

Answer (score 0):

Try to stay away from `sshpass` unless you have no other choice, its not the most secure.

Key your system using `ssh-keygen`, and copying the contents of `id_rsa.pub` to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Once you have keyed it, you will not need to put in a pass.  you can then create an alias or a shell script to login with whatever you prefer.

Comment: that's not my server, and I have an account there for my exercises in c++ with no any serious permissions and access to important data, I don't think anyone will need my c++ clumsy code :) but thanks, anyway

Comment: np, you can put your pass in a file only you can read and point sshpass to it, I would do that if you are going to use it.  But if its just for this its not that big a deal.. Just use a diff pass :-)